# Swift: Import locations from Healthkit Workouts / When have all queries finished?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I need to import location details from HK Workouts.

So far, it works out nicely, but I need to find out at which point all queries have been finished so I can process the collected data in total. Basically I need to get a trigger when the last HKWorkoutRouteQuery has been done.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

```
import HealthKit
import CoreLocation

var routeLocations: [CLLocation] = []

func getWorkouts() {
    
    routeLocations.removeAll()
    
    let distance = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.meter(), doubleValue: 1000)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: .greaterThanOrEqualTo, totalDistance: distance)
    
    let workoutQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: .workoutType(), predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: []) { (queryWorkout, workoutSamples, workoutError) in
                    
        guard let workoutSamples = workoutSamples as? [HKWorkout], workoutError == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        for workoutSample in workoutSamples {
            getRoutes(workoutSample: workoutSample)
        }
        
    }
        
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    healthStore.execute(workoutQuery)
    
}

func getRoutes(workoutSample: HKWorkout) {
    
    let workoutObjectQuery = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: workoutSample)
                               
    let routeQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: HKSeriesType.workoutRoute(), predicate: workoutObjectQuery, anchor: nil, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit) { (queryRoute, routeSamples, deletedRouteObjects, routeAnchor, routeError) in
                                       
        guard routeError == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        guard routeSamples != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        if routeSamples!.count == 0 {
            return
        }
        
        for routeSample in routeSamples! {
            getLocationsFromRoute(workoutSample: workoutSample, workoutRouteSample: routeSample)
        }
        
    }
    
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    healthStore.execute(routeQuery)
    
}


func getLocationsFromRoute(workoutSample: HKWorkout, workoutRouteSample: HKSample) {
    
    let routeSampleQuery = HKWorkoutRouteQuery(route: workoutRouteSample as! HKWorkoutRoute) { (queryRouteSample, locationsOrNil, done, errorOrNil) in
        
        if errorOrNil != nil || locationsOrNil == nil {
            return
        }
        
        handleWorkoutRouteLocations(workout: workoutSample, locations: locationsOrNil ?? [])
        
    }
    
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    healthStore.execute(routeSampleQuery)
    
}


func handleWorkoutRouteLocations(workout: HKWorkout, locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
    routeLocations.append(contentsOf: locations)
    
    print("\(routeLocations.count) entries in total")
    
}
```

Comment: You can use DispatchGroup to keep track of all the background calls and when they are done. If you want to get the new Xcode and Swift 5.5 there are some new tools coming. But I expect that you'll want DispatchGroups for now.

Comment: Thank you very much! This definitely helps!

Comment: Why not use the `done` parameter of `HKWorkoutRouteQuery`?